# Tooltip flickers when in iframe in chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tested in Chrome and IE.  It only occurs in Chrome.  I have Version 34.0.1847.131m.

The entire iframe flickers when you hover over and leave a tooltip.  There are other questions about the tooltip being on a specific side of a button. It does not matter.  The entire iframe flickers.

You can use the Bootstrap example for tooltips in an iframe to see this behavior:

```
<iframe src="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips" width="1024" height="2000" ></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3xUh/

Is there any workaround available to make it stop flickering?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after finding a Issue report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339893

It sounded like CSS animation could be to blame so I set animation to false on the tooltip and the flicker no longer occurs.